# How to use boost::log named_scope with boost::asio::yield_context?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log, boost-coroutine, boost-context

The thing is that when there are coroutines they can work in random order, and they can end up but

```
BOOST_LOG_NAMED_SCOPE(...)
```

keeps scope's name on each stackframe being oblivious to the fact that those stackframes are not nested, so they can be destructed in any order, not to mention that it's not that hard to put on a scenario where the scope according to `boost::log::named_scope` is different from the actual one.

How to make `boost:log` compatible with `boost::coroutine` and `boost::context` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named scopes in Boost.Log are maintained per-thread, using a thread-local storage, and consequently are incompatible with coroutines.

If you want a similar functionality with coroutines, you will have to implement a separate attribute that maintains a list of scopes in a coroutine-local storage. You can use [Boost.Intrusive](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/intrusive.html) to implement the list itself. On Windows, you could use [fiber-local storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/fibers) to place the list. On other systems you will probably have to use the stack.

The above applies to stackful coroutines. Stack-less coroutines do not have a dedicated stack, so it is not possible to maintain a dedicated list of scopes that pertains to activity of a given coroutine.

Comment: I *think* it's possible to have state - including dynamically allocated - in custom C++20-coro promise types. In fact, ASIO likely already uses that to contain associated (inner) executor, cancellation slot and allocator.

Comment: @sehe, BEST IDEA EVER! (on state)

Comment: @unegare I looked at it yesterday. It seems like you'll have to come up with a custom macro that uses the name_scope sentry on a scoped_logger_guard instead of scoped_thread_guard, but that should work. You might go all in and create an awaitable that returns the coro logger instance (like `co_await this_coro::logger`)